# How do I add a month to a NaiveDate with chronoutil?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I've been going through the documentation for `chrono` and [`chronoutil`](https://docs.rs/chronoutil/latest/chronoutil/) for Rust but I think I am missing something when trying to add a month to a `NaiveDate`.

I have a very simple Rust program:

```
use chrono::NaiveDate;
use chronoutil::relative_duration::RelativeDuration;

fn main() {

    let start = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2020, 1, 31);
    let one_month = RelativeDuration::months(1);
    let end = start + one_month;
    println!("{}", end.format("%Y-%m-%d").to_string());

}
```

But I am getting a mismatched types error on compile

```
     let end = start + one_month;
                       ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `chrono::Duration`, found struct `RelativeDuration`
```

It doesn't seem very happy with me adding the RelativeDuration to the NaiveDate.

Including dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.2.16"
chronoutil = "0.2.3"
```

Comment: Any reason why not `let end = start.checked_add_months(1)` ? [NaiveDate::checked_add_months](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html#method.checked_add_months)

Comment: That's strange because it almost looks like the basic example of the `chronoutil` crate... if you try `use chronoutil::RelativeDuration`, does it work?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I tried `checked_add_months` but it got a different error `help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `checked_add``

Comment: @BlackBeans I know right! I did try with `chronoutil::RelativeDuration` but got pretty much the same error

Comment: You're using an insanely old version of `chrono`. You can't upgrade?

Comment: @isaactfa I will try to upgrade and check

Comment: I still don't think you can add a `RelativeDuration` to a `NaiveDate` but should be able to use `.checked_add_months(Months::new(1))` then.

Comment: @isaactfa you were right but it seems the newer version of `chrono` supports months anyway. Does that mean that chronoutils has become redundant?

Comment: I've never used it, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: @isaactfa thanks for being so helpful though. I can't justify using `chronoutil` for my needs with all the new `chrono` features but thanks so much for your help